Why doesn't my Azure Active Directory SSO auth token contain application permissions permissions?
So, I have created an APP(registered an APP) in my microsoft entra account(@firstaccount.onmicrosoft.com). This account is one of two seperate tenent accounts I have.
Name of this APP is 'Test_APP_1'
In the Authentication tab of this APP,

I have selected 'Supported Account Types' as 'Multitenant'.
In the advanced settings 'Allow public client flows', I have selected yes.

In the 'API Permissions' tab of this APP,

I have added microsoft graph permissions.
I selected few deligated permissions
and few Application permissions.

Once this is done.
Using Java,
PublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplication.builder(CLIENT_ID_TEST_APP_1)
    .authority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common")
    .build();
Set<String> scopes = Collections.singleton("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
InteractiveRequestParameters parameters = InteractiveRequestParameters
    .builder(new URI(REDIRECT_URI))
    .scopes(scopes)
    .build();

CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireToken(parameters);
IAuthenticationResult result = future.get();
System.out.println("Access Token: " + result.accessToken());IAuthenticationResult result = future.get();        

Using the above code, I call the Microsoft Identity provider page, log in with my second account(@secondaccount.onmicrosoft.com), This is my second account of different tenant.
This account is an admin account, so It asks for permissions consent, then app gets authenticated, then an 'service principal' gets created in this second tenant account.
This app in this second account also has both deligated and application permissions in the 'API permissions' tab.
But, after the authentication, the above code receives an access token, which gets printed in the java program.
This access token does not contain the 'roles' key, which is the application permissions.
I need an access token to both deligated and application permissions. How can I get it?
I have tried the 'Expose an API' method, in which I create another app with scopes and app roles. This method is not working when I log in with my second tenant account.
Am I missing something?

Can you include the API permission balde of the application?

token decoded roles shows the Permissions of Application Type, not include the Delegated ones. You can check it in your app API Permission blade.

This is a valid scenario. Application and Delegated scopes are fundamentally different, and the OAuth grant being used defines which type is requested (Auth Code == Delegated, Client Credentials == Application).
Delegated scopes are used when operating on behalf of a signed-in user. You will often see this scenario referred to as "App+User."
Application scopes are used when operating without a signed-in user. This is commonly find this scenario referred to as "App-Only".
Since you obviously can't both have a signed-in user and not have a signed-in user, the two classes of scopes are mutually exclusive.
You must request two distinct tokens when calling a mixed set of endpoints. The good news is that the client credentials grant is a single call, so there is little overhead to fetching an app-only token when needed.
